# Mismatch between utxo increase and total utxos

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli, utxo-set, getblockstats

I'm running bitcoin core and using the commands getblockstats and gettxoutsetinfo.

I ran gettxoutsetinfo at block 770992 and it showed a total of 83,420,287 unspent transaction outputs. I then waited for block 770993 to appear and ran getblockstats for that block.

In getblockstats it shows a utxo_increase field, which is the difference between the outs and ins fields (outputs created - outputs consumed). For block 770993 it showed -603.

I ran gettxoutsetinfo at block 770993 and it shows a total of 83,419,633 utxos. Why doesn't it match up?

I tested it for a couple previous blocks as well and the same thing happened. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `utxo_increase` and `utxo_size_inc` fields of `getblockstats` does not exclude provably unspendable outputs. However provably unspendable outputs will not be added to the UTXO set, so `gettxoutsetinfo` will not count them.